# Can i make a group radiobutton as a group of pressed button, not as a group of circles with one point? (PyQt4)

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4, qradiobutton

If I use `tkinter`, I can set the  option `indicatoron = 0`, and get an expected effect.

This effect can be achieved with a group of `QPushButton`, and some additional code, I suppose.

But is it a true way? Maybe, `PyQt` has an option, as `tkinter`?

This code gave me an expected effect from tkinter.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
var = IntVar()
button1 = Radiobutton(root,indicatoron=0,text=' One Button ',variable=var,value=1)
button2 = Radiobutton(root,indicatoron=0,text=' Two Button ',variable=var,value=2)
button3 = Radiobutton(root,indicatoron=0,text='Three Button',variable=var,value=3)
button1.place(x=4, y=4)
button2.place(x=4, y=30)
button3.place(x=4, y=56)
mainloop()
```

Comment: Please add some code of your attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PyQt, you can use `QPushButton` and a `QButtonGroup`:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.buttonGroup = QtGui.QButtonGroup(self)
        for text in 'One Two Three'.split():
            button = QtGui.QPushButton(text)
            button.setCheckable(True)
            layout.addWidget(button)
            self.buttonGroup.addButton(button)
        self.buttonGroup.buttonClicked.connect(self.handleButtons)

    def handleButtons(self, button):
        print('Button %s Clicked' % button.text())

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```